# CSS first-child issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following li:before styles:

```
header nav ul li:before, ul.meta li:before, footer nav ul li:before { content: "\2605"; }
```

I am trying to get the first-child li to have content: ""; yet I cannot for the life of met figure it out. I've tried

```
header nav ul li:first-child { content: ""; }
```

and it doesn't work. I've tried

```
header > nav > ul > li:fist-child { content: ""; }
```

and it doesn't work. I've tried giving the nav and ID and using

```
nav#topnav ul li:first-child { content: ""; }
```

and it doesn't work. I've also tried giving the ul an ID and it doesn't work. Basically I'm stuck. I can't figure this out and am starting to think it's not possible to have the content: ""; when there is a :before class but I also can't find any documentation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the `first-child` and `before` selectors.  You must, because the `content` rule is on the pseudo element rather than the element itself.

```
header nav ul li:first-child:before { content: ""; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/KcGKr/

Comment: Wow. I figured it was going to be something completely simply I was missing. Thank you.